# Xamarin.Forms alternative to StartActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ringtonemanager

I am currently trying to get the Uri selected from a `RingtoneManager.ActionRingtonePicker`. I put in all my extra settings and set the appropriate flag.
However I am only able to call `StartActivity(intent)`. Is there anyway for me to get the selection from the Ringtone Picker and use the `intent.getParceableExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtonePickedUri);`. My code is below and if I can replace the `context.StartActivity(intent)` with a work around then that would be great.

```
public async Task<string> pickAndReceiveRingtone(string currentUri)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ActionRingtonePicker);
    intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneShowSilent, false);
    intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneTitle, "Select a ringtone");
    intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneShowDefault, false);
    intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneType, (int)RingtoneType.Alarm);
    intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneExistingUri, RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Alarm));
    intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);

    //Replace below
    /*await*/ context.StartActivity(intent);

    //Grab selected uri here
    currentUri = ...
    return  currentUri;

}
```

Comment: Use `StartActivityForResult()` instead of `StartActivity()` will be a good choice, and then you can get the selection from the Ringtone Picker in `OnActivityResult()` method.

Comment: @YorkShen my question specifically says I can't use `StartActivityForResult()` which is literally the entire reason for this question.

Comment: Could you please tell me why you cant use `StartActivityForResult()` method?  Because it always return `Result.Cancel` in  `OnActivityResult` method,  cant get the selection from the Ringtone Picker  so you want use another work around?

Comment: @YorkShen  basically its being called from a Android class using Dependency Service and not an Android Activity which is why it doesn't have that method. Maybe I could pass in the Context or Activity and do some conversions to make it doable?

Comment: @YorkShen thinking of going to an android activity and then popping up the ringtones. Right now the button to open the ringtone picker comes from a DisplayActionSheet call on a Xamarin.Forms Content Page

Comment: I have post my answer, can this achieve your desired function?

Comment: @YorkShen im just at work but I'll check when I get home and ill confirm if it answered or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Xamarin.Forms exists in an Activity, OnActivityResult method in Activity still can be called.

In your `DependencyService` class, use the `StartActivityForResult()` method like this :

```
public void StartActivityInAndroid()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ActionRingtonePicker);
    intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneShowSilent, false);
    intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneTitle, "Select a ringtone");
    intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneShowDefault, false);
    intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneType, (int)RingtoneType.Alarm);
    intent.PutExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtoneExistingUri, RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Alarm));

    //intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);// remember to delete this

    var activity = Forms.Context as Activity;

    activity.StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Then, you can receive the result in `OnActivityResult` method like this :

```
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode != Result.Ok)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Android.Net.Uri uri = (Android.Net.Uri)data.GetParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.ExtraRingtonePickedUri);
            Log.Debug("onActivityResult====", "" + uri);

            Toast.MakeText(this, uri + "", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            if (uri != null)
            {
                switch (requestCode)
                {
                    case 0:
                        RingtoneManager.SetActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneType.Ringtone, uri);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where should I be overriding the `OnActivityResult()`? The activity that needs it overwritten is the ActionRingtonePicker but it doesn't have it own file. Should I make an activity that inherits it and override it there, then proceed to call that type of activity instead?

Comment: @B Best, Normally you should override the OnActivityResult() in your MainActivity, and you can get the Activity's type by debugging at var activity = Forms.Context .

Comment: The line `RingtoneManager.SetActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneType.Alarm, uri)` just makes sure if they open it up again it shows the one they previously selected already chosen correct?

Comment: @B Best, this method just sets the Uri of the default sound for a given sound type. I wrote this just want to point that you could get the selection from the Ringtone Picker  in this line.

Comment: I see, I've already handled that somewhere else I believe. I'm just trying to figure out how to return the uri back to the Class that called the StartActivityForResult() now

Comment: Or rather when you set the new default as the picked one you just refer to that I'm understanding that now

Comment: @B Best, you want get the uri in PCL?

Comment: Yes I'd like to save it to my own Alarm class so it can be referenced later when activated again.

Comment: @B Best, You could use [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/) to implement this feature, [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/UsingMessagingCenter/) is a sample about hoe to use MessagingCenter.

Comment: Its passing the right uri all the way to a Controller class I have which is using `PutExtra()` on and Intent but for whatever reason the values aren't getting through. If I fix that it should work fine. Thanks!

Comment: Just didn't know to put the `PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent` to allow the passed in variables to be received properly. Everything works great now!